# A Java question

Tags: java

```
public interface MyInterface {    
  public void display();
}

public class MyClass implements MyInterface {

private MyInterface my1;

 public void display(){
  my1.display();
 }

}
```

How is it working?Is it correct? How so?
Where can i get more on delegation?

Comment: @Salandur, that is a valid question, and as long as it is not a homework question, it is never too basic for stackoverflow.

Comment: I think too basic is the wrong term. It's too vague. The answer to your quesetion is "because the java compiler compiles that into bytecote to run on the java virtual machine.

Comment: Could You be more specific about what you wan't to achieve ?

Comment: @Salundur: your spelling mistakes are too basic to make here.

Comment: This will work, provided m1 is set to an object.  This is called delegation. if m1 is not set i.e. it is null, you will get a NullPointerException if you call display()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few problems with your code. I will point out how to correct them and then move on to explain what is going on.

### Bugs in your code

First, your `MyInterface` needs to be declared like this:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    public void display();
}
```

Notice that you didn't include the `interface` keyword in your code.

Second, your `MyClass` needs to be declared like this:

```
public class MyClass implements MyInterface {
    // All the stuff you already have inside MyClass
    // (I don't feel like typing it all out)
}
```

Notice that you didn't include the `class` keyword in your code.

### Explaining your code

I presume you are using `MyClass` like this:

```
MyClass myVariable = new MyClass();
myVariable.display();
```

You could also do it like this:

```
MyInterface myVariable = new MyClass();
myVariable.display();
```

Regardless of which way you do it, you are always going to have a `NullPointerException` thrown whenever you call the `display()` method. The reason why you receive this `NullPointerException` can be found on this line:

```
my1.display();
```

Java throws a `NullPointerException` whenever you attempt to call a method on a `null` object. In your code, `my1` will **always** be `null` (because you never assign it a value). Therefore, Java will always throw a `NullPointerException` when it tries to run `my1.display()`.

### What I *think* your code should be doing

I *think* you're trying to do something like this:

```
public class MyClass implements MyInterface {

    public void display() {
        // The actual display code
        System.out.println("I am displaying");
    }

}
```

Or, you could be trying to keep the `my1` field, but actually assign it a value via the `MyClass` constructor:

```
public class MyClass implements MyInterface {

    private MyInterface my1;

    public MyClass(MyInterface someValue) {
        my1 = someValue;
    }

    public void display() {
        my1.display();
    }

}
```

Comment: the keywords class and interface were missed out sorry i have edited it

Answer (score 1):

**1. Situation** will cause to the **NullPointerException** because it will call (1) then (2) after that (3) that **my1 is null** and it will throw `NullPointerException`

```
interface MyInterface {
   public void display();
}

 public class MyClass  implements MyInterface {
 private MyInterface my1; // 3

 public void display() { // 1
     my1.display(); // 2
 } 

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    new MyClass().display(); 

 }
}
```

**2. Situation** Lets' assign MyInterface with MyClass. Let's see what will happen. First of all it will call (1) then (2) then again (3) so again it will call (2) again that cause to **StackOverflowError** (infinite recursion)

```
interface MyInterface {
 public void display();
 }

 public class MyClass  implements MyInterface {
       private  MyInterface my1;

       public void display() { //2 
            my1.display(); //3
       }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass m = new MyClass();
        m.my1 = m;
        m.display(); //1

       }
  }
```

I think it will be helpful to you. If you have any question please ask.